# Is eigenvalue multiplied by constant also an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be an $n × n$ matrix.
>
> If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $c$ is a nonzero scalar, then $c\lambda$ is another eigenvalue of $A$.

I found this on "Linear Algebra and its applications (Jim Defranza)", summary of Chapter 5.

It is acceptable, that eigenvectors multiplied by constant is ok, cause $A(cv) = cAv = c\lambda v = \lambda(cv)$.

But I don't understand $c\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question, and good catch!

It's a typo/brain-o. The author surely meant to write "If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and ..."